# update parent data from recursive child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would to implement of file tree view with html and vuejs for this I have a recursive component to implement the file tree with multiple roots like this:

`Root 1
 - elemnt 1.1
 - elemnt 1.2
 - ...
Root 2
 - element 2.1
 - element 2.2`

I want to save the latest clicked item, so how can I do this?

This is the relative code of the component:

```
Vue.component('item', {
        template: `
        <li>
            <div @click='toggle(category)'>
                {{category.name}}

            <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
                <item v-for='category in category.children' :category='category'></item>
            </ul>
        </li>
        `,
        props: {
            category: Object
        },
        data(){
            return {
                open: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isFolder: function() {
                return this.category.children && this.category.children.length
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle(category){
                if (this.isFolder) {
                    this.open = !this.open
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

This is the HTML

```
<ul>
            <item v-for='cat in categories' :category='cat'></item>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Checkout the [component basics](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) it's a good read, as is most of the vue documentation, and goes through some good design patterns and solutions to solve this 'problem' ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is reactivity in depth, the VueJS documentation provides a good explanation: [Reactiviy in Depth - How Changes Are Tracked](http://Reactivity%20in%20Depth%20-%20How%20Changes%20Are%20Tracked)

There are several ways to trigger the rendering of components. The most  obvious one would be `this.$forceUpdate()`. However it is forcing ever component to to rerendered and I wouldn't recommend using it. If triggered several times in a short time, it could get slow.

The next two solutions are compared much better only the component without others.

First way to trigger rendering:

```
<script>
export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            treeData: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateTree () {
            const treeData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.treeData))
            this.treeData = []
            this.$nextTick(function () => {
                this.treeData = treeData
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Or you could simply use `v-if` on the parent and call `this.$emit('updateTree')` from the children:

```
<template>
    <child-component @update="updateTree" :treeData="treeData" />
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent'
export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            showTree: true,
            treeData: []
        }
    },
    components: { 'child-component' : ChildComponent },
    methods: {
        fetchAPIData () {
            // ... ajax
            this.treeData = apiResponse
        },
        updateTree () {
            this.showTree = false
            this.$nextTick(function () => {
                this.showTree = true
            })
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.fetchAPIData()
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answert, but this not solve my problem, what I want is the save the latest clicked element in a variable in the parent data, if I use your approach the only elements that saved are the roots, but when clicked other elements the variable doesn't change

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I just updated my answer :).